# Get number of modified rows after sqlite3 execute in Python

Tags: python, c, sqlite

When performing SQL statements such as `UPDATE`, and `INSERT`, the usual `.fetch*()` methods on the `Cursor` instance obviously don't apply to the number of **rows modified**.

In the event of executing one of the aforementioned statements, what is the correct way to obtain the corresponding row count in Python, and the corresponding API in the Sqlite3 C interface?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

After calling your `Cursor.execute*()` methods with your UPDATE or INSERT statements you can use `Cursor.rowcount` to see the # of rows affected by the execute call.

If I had to guess I would say the python lib is calling [`int sqlite3_changes(sqlite3*)`](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/changes.html) from the C API but I have not looked at the code so I can't say for sure.

Comment: and teh corresponding C function?

Comment: Edited with educated guess of the C API being used.

Comment: [Link to relevant Python documentation here.](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.Cursor.rowcount)