# How do I determine if a Python sqlite UPDATE worked?

Tags: python, sqlite

I'm using sqlite3 in Python. I want to know if my UPDATE statement worked or not without doing another database query:

```
c.execute('update students set gpa=3.5 where stuid=123')
```

If there isn't a student with stuid 123 then obviously the update fails.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2316003/get-number-of-modified-rows-after-sqlite3-execute

Answer (score 52, accepted):

[`cursor.rowcount`](http://docs.python.org/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.Cursor.rowcount) will be 1 if the update was successful (affecting 1 row) or 0 if it failed.

Comment: This also appears to work when determining if a row (or rows) were successfully deleted.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

For a slightly more complete answer for if you want to handle error and success:

```
c.execute('update students set gpa=3.5 where stuid=123')

if c.rowcount < 1:
    #error
else:
    #success
```

Answer (score 0):

```
command = """Update Table_Name SET col1 = 2 WHERE col2 = 1"""
            dbconn.execute(command)
            sqliteconn.commit()
            if dbconn.rowcount > 0:
                print("Update Statement Executed Successfully")
```