# SQLite3 Python - Check if query is successful

Tags: python, sqlite

My query is:

```
connection.execute("UPDATE notifyTable set notified = 1 WHERE coinMarketValue < value AND notified = 0")
```

How would I check if this has been executed?

For example:

```
if query is True:
    code
```

I could not find a solution for this specifically. Instead, I selected from the table and only queried the table if certain conditions were met.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I determine if a Python sqlite UPDATE worked?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5006835/how-do-i-determine-if-a-python-sqlite-update-worked)

Answer (score 0):

Check if [rowcount](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/sqlite3.html?highlight=sqlite#sqlite3.Cursor.rowcount) is useful in your cases.

Answer (score -2):

Consider using exception

```
success_flg = True
try:
    connection.execute("UPDATE notifyTable set notified = 1 WHERE coinMarketValue < value AND notified = 0")
except:
    success_flg = False
```

Comment: This doesn't capture the case when the query ran properly but no rows were updated, which is probably what OP wants. See [How do I determine if a Python sqlite UPDATE worked?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5006835/how-do-i-determine-if-a-python-sqlite-update-worked/5006914#5006914)